# Metro theme for website

Tags: jquery, css, themes

Anyone know of an easy way to style a website with a windows phone 7 like metro theme ?
Either a `CSS` or a `jQuery`-based theme would work.

Comment: See this.
http://jqmetro.codeplex.com

Comment: I'm not sure why they closed this question.  It seems that plenty of readers understood what I was asking.  And the answer with 50 votes below indicates that in can, in fact, be answered.  I was asking for something like a jQuery theme or twitter bootstrap library that implemented a "metro" design.  (No big deal, but why needlessly discourage users?  Especially 6 months after the fact?)

Comment: I know, I'm terrible for commenting on an old post, but here is one that is worth looking into, as well: http://metroui.org.ua

Comment: You can use [bootmetro](http://aozora.github.com/bootmetro/index.html). It is a bootstrap theme with metro style.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This can help:

https://github.com/mvalipour/jq-metro

**UPDATE (Sep 2011):**

The library is now becoming more complete towards supporting all metro-style controls and a jquery-mobile extension for developing metro-style HTML5 mobile apps.

Comment: Unsure the reason you're being downvoted/flagged as spam; this is a legitimate answer.

Comment: // , Why did they move off of Github?

Answer (score 10):

Try out http://jquit.com/builder. It's a nice tool for generating Metro UI themes for jQuery UI. You can configure the colors to match your website's color scheme.

Answer (score 5):

This question was asked a long time ago but since it still shows up in a search...

Very nice looking metro UI: http://metroui.org.ua/

Seams to look better in IE due to anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 4):

This site provides a full php/html/css/javascript framework for metro ui:

http://metro-webdesign.info/#home

Answer (score 3):

Well here's another Jquery metro plugin. [Metro JS](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=metro%20js&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFUQFjAA&url=http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs&ei=9ZDjT4gNjorxBIaklYYI&usg=AFQjCNG28ZW9uZB_U8g2LwHXP22nwo6-zg&cad=rja). Actually it's quite impressive. You should give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Found another one here: http://forr.st/~5n3

Seems to be more based on tiles rather than menus, though.

Answer (score 0):

Not to sound flippant, but CSS? ASP.NET MVC 3 doesn't (to my knowledge) use controls like ASP.NET does, so you're writing and styling the views yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for the actual css to replace the default css.  I guess it wouldn't be that tough but if someone else has done it...

Comment: It would be a very nice thing to have; I was doing something similar but have now diverged a little from the Windows Phone Design Guidelines so I doubt it would be especially useful for you.