# Any good free Metro css/js controls pack?

Tags: javascript, .net, css, microsoft-metro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Metro theme for website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330426/metro-theme-for-website)

I want to be able to create a webpage which is absolutely the same as the normal metro apps. Also I want it to have the tilting on click and the effects.
Is there a javascript library which does that? Or can I get somehow the css/js animations directly from Microsoft's styles?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330426/metro-theme-for-website

Comment: None of the sites in the link have the tilting effect. Can't I somehow copy the original?

Comment: how about this one http://snipplr.com/view/59777/

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Wijmo](http://wijmo.com/). Wijmo has an open (free) and a complete (paid) version. They have two different metro themes which can be viewed [here](http://wijmo.com/demo/explore/?showall=true).

You can create yourself a Metro jQuery UI Theme [here](http://jquit.com/build-jquery-ui-themes-with-jquit-builder/).